# Restore Purchase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add a restore button to my app, I have a non-consumable inApp purchase and the purchase part works fine. I have a button that calls this two methods:

```
product_id = "RemoveAdsIAP";
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

and this the purchasing code:

```
func buyConsumable(){
    succssessIAP = false
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
    } else {
        displayErrorAlert()
    }
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
}

func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    var count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        var validProducts = response.products
        var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else { }
    } else {
        displayErrorAlert()
    }
}

func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    activityIndicatorShop.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    displayErrorAlert()
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    succssessIAP = false
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased, .Restored:
                if (product_id == "GetNextFactIAP" && succssessIAP == false) {
                    startController.getData()
                    startController.hideContainerView()
                    succssessIAP = true
                }
                if (product_id == "RemoveAdsIAP" && succssessIAP == false) {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "viewAdsBool")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                    startController.removeOnce()
                    disableAds(true)
                    succssessIAP = true
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                activityIndicatorShop.stopAnimating()
                displayErrorAlert()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the button nothing happens, I've added a log statement to check if the updatedTransactions method was called and it wasn't, What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add the button as an IBAction.

Read this...

http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
  import UIKit
import StoreKit
 
class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{

    var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()
    
    // 2
    func buyProduct() {
        println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }
    
    //3
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product request")
        var myProduct = response.products
        
        for product in myProduct {
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)
            
            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }
        
        outRemoveAds.enabled = true
        outAddCoins.enabled = true
    }
    
    // 4
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("transactions restored")
        
        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction
            
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            
            switch prodID {
            case "seemu.iap.removeads":
                println("remove ads")
                removeAds()
            case "seemu.iap.addcoins":
                println("add coins to account")
                addCoins()
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }
            
        }
    }
 
    // 5
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("add paymnet")
        
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            var trans = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction
            println(trans.error)
            
            switch trans.transactionState {
                
            case .Purchased:
                println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
                println(p.productIdentifier)
                
                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID {
                    case "seemu.iap.removeads":
                        println("remove ads")
                        removeAds()
                    case "seemu.iap.addcoins":
                        println("add coins to account")
                        addCoins()
                    default:
                        println("IAP not setup")
                }
                
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            default:
                println("default")
                break;
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    // 6
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        println("finish trans")
    }
 
    //7
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        println("remove trans");
    }
```

Comment: What happens when a user wants to restore a purchase?